# Небольшое недопонимание с массивом указателей

Tags: c, указатели

Почему так работает?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int *p1[1] = {2018};
    char *p2[1] = {"abcd"};

    p1[0] = p2[0];

    printf("%s\n\n", p1[0]); /* выводит abcd */

   return 0;
}
```

Мы же создаем массив из одного элемента, который является указателем на int. Если происходит приведение к типу char*, то почему оно происходит без потери информации?

Comment: Где по Вашему должна происходить потеря информации?

Comment: Почему в заголовке вопроса (и в коде) фигурируют какие-то одноэлементные массивы? Вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к массивам и ничего существенно связанного с массивами в нем нет.

Comment: @AnT как посоветуете озаглавить?

Comment: @non_grata: Мне трудно советовать, ибо я в упор не понимаю, в чем именно вы увидели важность массивов в этом вопросе. Это у вас надо спросить - в чем? Почему вы использовали `int *p1[1]` и `char *p2[1]` вместо просто обычных переменных `int *p1` и `char *p2`? Абсолютно ничего в вашем коде принципиально не зависит от "массивности" `p1` и `p2`. Почему тогда массивы?

Comment: @AnT вы не поверите, но этому есть объяснение. К вашему счастью, я не хочу отвлекать вас своими "тараканами", будет достаточно того, что я "плаваю" в указателях.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сразу стоит заметить, что абсолютно ничего в вашем коде не имеет какой-то принципиальной связи с массивами. Массивы тут совершено ни к чему и ни на что не влияют. Почему вы использовали массивы размера 1 вместо обычных переменных - не ясно.

Далее: ваш код не "работает". Его поведение не определено, ибо он не является корректной программой на языке С.

```
int *p1[1] = {2018};
```

Это попытка инициализации указателя типа `int *` целочисленным значением `2018`. Это constraint violation, т.е. ошибка. Стандартным языком С это не поддерживается. Такое преобразование типов требует *явного приведения типа (каста)*.

```
p1[0] = p2[0];
```

Это попытка присваивания указателя типа `char *` в переменную типа `int *`. Это constraint violation, т.е. ошибка. Стандартным языком С это не поддерживается. Такое преобразование типов требует *явного приведения типа (каста)*.

```
printf("%s\n\n", p1[0]);
```

Спецификатор формата `%s` требует аргумента типа `char *`. Вы передали `int *`. Поведение не определено.

Ваш компилятор сообщил вам об этих нарушениях, но вы, очевидно, проигнорировали диагностические сообщения компилятора. Независимо от того, согласился ли ваш компилятор "скомпилировать" этот код, программа написана не на языке С и ее поведение никак не оговаривается языком С.

Возьмите в привычку первым делом проверять свой код в online компиляторе GCC с флагом `-pedantic-errors` и многие бессмысленные вопросы отпадут сами собой

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/823471ccc0b42efa

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к предыдущим ответам хочу сказать, что когда вы пишите код:

```
printf("%s\n\n", p1[0]);
```

то printf выводит значения всех встреченных байт от текущей позиции (адреса p1[0]) и пока не встетит `\0`. Спецификатор `%s` не проверяет что находится по указанному адресу, он означает что выводится все до нулевого байты. Так если вы поменяете присваивание, то все также будет работать, но выведет уже не `abcd`, а какю-то билеберду в которой первые 4 символа будут всегда одинаковы (это число 2018 - выведет, конечно, не число, а значения его байт), а остальные - их может быть разное количество и содержать они могут что угодно.

Answer (score 1):

В присваивании `p1[0] = p2[0];` не происходит преобразования типов, поэтому и не происходит потери информации. Просто один указатель скопирован в другой. Так как оба указателя по 4 (или 8 байт, если платформа 64бита), то никаких проблем. В строке вывода мы говорим printf - возьми значение по указателю и трактуй как строку (потому что `%s`) и выведи. И ничего странного.

Просто си это язык, который допускает достаточного много "вольностей". "правильный компилятор" должен был в двух (а точнее - в четырех) местах настучать по пальцам.

Comment: "В присваивании p1[0] = p2[0]; не происходит преобразования типов" - это как это??? Слева - `int *`, справа - `char *`. Требуется преобразование типа. Такое присваивание в С запрещено именно потому, ибо в С нет неявного *преобразования типов* из `char *` в  `int *`. Язык С не допускает таких "вольностей".

Comment: я просто оставлю это здесь https://ideone.com/RqJJSL  - все компилируется. В с++ да, так нельзя просто делать. В си - можно (но не значит, что нужно).

Comment: "Комипилируется" - это глюки вашего компилятора, к языку С никакого отношения не имеющие. А уж ссылаться на ideone (!), втихую фильтрующий сообщения компилятора, здесь не принято вообще. Смотрите сами: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc0973e43decc1a2 Правила контроля типов указателей в С++ и С почти в точности совпадают.

Comment: Специально для вас в стандарт языка С была добавлена фраза "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, **shall be specified by means of an explicit cast**." хотя и без этой фразы стандарты языка всегда были однозначны по этому вопросу. Однако какое-то странное  верование, что якобы в С это делать "можно", продолжает жить по сей день.

Comment: вот, уже нужно только специальный компилятор, и только с pedantic:).  И во вторых, если уж ссылаетесь на стандарт, то нужно хоть упомянуть, какой именно из - с89, с90, с99, с11. А они немножечко отличаются. А если копнуть более старые версии... или различные компиляторы... И да, "можно" имеет много значений.

Comment: Тут нужен не "специальный компилятор", а 1) понимание того, что по умолчанию многие компиляторы С исторически рапортуют многие ошибки как "предупреждения", 2) умение невооруженным взглядом распознать ошибку, отрапортованную, как "предупреждение". Если этого нет, то тогда действительно остается только искать "специальный компилятор". (По ссылке, кстати, обычный GCC, ничего специального.) Что же касается версии стандарта - я ее не упоминал, ибо все версии стандарта языка С в этом отношении единодушны.